# Splunk Fields - Broken

Tags: csv, field, splunk

I was going to ask this on the Splunk forums, but for some reason I haven't got a validation email after a few hours and multiple attempts, so I thought I would try here.

I create a search from a `.csv` data source and save a report from this search. I then selected the fields I want. Screenshot:

[image: Selected Fields]

This works great. Then I send this report over to a dashboard so I can make some nice graphs and all the fields are gone and I have no option to map the fields.

[image: bad data]

(redacted some data)

As you can see there's no option to use the fields I selected in the report even though this is an import of that report. I tried manually mapping a field, and even that only shows up in the `Reports` view and not in any dashboards/panels. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go to the report and choose the "Add to dashboard" option. Keep both the report and the dashboard in the same app. "Permanent" fields are defined within the context of an app. "Temporary" fields (created by the `rex` command, for example) exist only within the context of a report.